# How can we set the scroll bar for list view with out setting the width and height?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

How can we set the scrolling for list view with out setting width and height?If I set the width and height it does not fit for all screen resolution. So I don't want to set the width and height. If the list view exceeds the four elements it should set the scrolling. How can it possible? any suggestions?

```
  <ul data-role="listview" id="locationList" data-dismissible="false" name="locationList" data-inset="true">
        <li><a>Element 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Element 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Element 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Element 4</a></li>
        <li><a>Element 5</a></li>
        <li><a>Element 6</a></li>                     
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your result there is also a pure jQuery code solution that does not require the addition of any class to your ul element
As you can see in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/D5z7G/2/) i only set the height of the ul tag, when the elements exceed number of 7 automatically tags becomes overflow scroll
You also have two buttons for increase or decrease the li tag length and see the script in action
When you pass a function as the value of a css property within the css method of jQuery(see checklen function) you can decide the value of that property according to certain parameters. In this case the number of li tag

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    function checkLen(len){
        $('#locationList').css('overflow-y',function(){
            if(len>7){return 'scroll'
                }else{return 'auto'}
            });
      };
    $('#a').click(function(){
        var len=$('ul li').length;
        $('<li><a>Element '+(len+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo('ul');
        checkLen(len);
        });
    $('#b').click(function(){
        $('li:last').remove();
        var len=$('ul li').length;
        checkLen(len);
        });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use width in %(percentage) instead in fix PX(pixel), It will work.

Comment: How can I use % for below statement,       style="width: 285px; height: 150px; overflow: auto"

Comment: If I set the width and height it does not fit for all screen resolution. So I don't want to set the width and height.
So to make it fit for mobile resolutions use %.

Answer (score 0):

For the scroll to work, you will have to provide height and width. However, you can use jquery to check the list items and if more than 4 items are present in it, then you can apply the height and width to it.

Also, for the scroll to appear you will have to make use of overflow property. So you can apply this when you list items are more than 4. You can create a class as such:

```
.showScroll {
    width:200px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow:scroll;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

and use jquery as such:

```
var countOfListItems = $("#locationList li").size();
if (countOfListItems > 4) {
    $("#locationList").toggleClass('showScroll');
}
```

Check this out here->http://jsfiddle.net/TVK43/1/. This should give you a better idea.

You can also try Sharanpreet's answer of using width in terms of %.

Hope this helps!!!